# Correctness of "Both are equally terrifying"

Tags: grammaticality

A quote attributed to Arthur C. Clarke says "Two possibilities exist: either we are alone in the Universe or we are not. Both are equally terrifying."

Is it grammatically correct? I think it should say "The two are equally terrifying" or "Both are terrifying, equally so".

Comment: What is in the original that makes you think it might not be correct?

Comment: @KillingTime "Both are equally terrifying" logically parses to "X is equally terrifying and Y is equally terrifying" which does not make sense.

Comment: "equally terrifying" presumes a binary operand, not a unary one is what I mean.

Comment: 'Both' as a pronoun means 'A and B'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't understand. Surely it should not be fine to say "Mary and Joan are Americans. Both are sisters."

Comment: The answer to the question whether the sentence is **grammatically** correct is: yes, obviously. What you are really asking is whether it is correct as a matter of something like **logical** syntax.

Comment: No, of course not. Few if any dictionary definitions use 'absolute synonyms'; there are contexts where the synonyms are _not_ interchangeable.  You've found an example like this. But  'Mary and Joan are Americans/Smiths/pensioners/here/tall/feeling sick ...' can be rendered 'Both are Americans/Smiths/pensioners/here/tall/feeling sick ...' if they've already been referred to by name. Note also that adding 'equally' only makes sense with certain examples / contexts.

Answer (score 2):

"Both" is a pronoun that stands for "the two possibilities", so it is correct. This form of reference to two entities by means of "both" is very common.